# How to re-enable syntax highlighting in Vim?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

**Vim language highlighting has quit working only for one specific file.**

I've been using Vim in WSL (Ubuntu) for several months now without problems. My PC is Windows 10 Professional. Strangely, Vim is no longer highlighting properly when I open a particular file.

Everything works fine with every other file, but if I open this one file, it does not display correctly. The syntax highlighting is gone. Line numbers, tabs, and end-of-file-tildes still follow the color scheme, but my actual code is simply colored white. Does anyone know how to fix this?

More details:

- The file type is `*.v`
- If I rename the file, it displays correctly.
- If multiple files are open at once (i.e. split view), every other file displays fine while this one file does not.
- The problem arose in the middle of a work session, and I changed nothing in the `vimrc` before the problem arose.
- After seeing the problem, I ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, followed by a restart.
- I tried changing the color scheme in my vimrc.

Nothing I tried worked. Any ideas or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It could be something odd saved in a view or a session file; have you tried `vim --clean -c 'syntax enable'`?

Comment: When you have the `*.v` file loaded, what does `:verbose set ft?` return? Does it help if you set `'filetype'` to a value that matches the language in the file (such as `:set filetype=v` or whatever might be the name of the language?)

Comment: I'm guessing Verilog? `:set ft=verilog` does that fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions!

I found a bunch of files under `~/.vim/view/` which seemed to provide file-specific configurations for all my source files. So I deleted the one that linked to my problematic Verilog file. It regenerated when I reopened the source file in Vim. Everything displays correctly now. The problem must have been that an auto-generated config file got corrupted somehow.

Comment: Indeed, you may have an autocommand that saves views and loads them—I’ve found this causes most people problems in the long run. You might be interested in viewoptions though